# How to start Spyder IDE installed using Python XY?

Tags: python, spyder

When I start the Spyder from the start menu it opens the cmd and then closes it immediately without opening the spyder.

Comment: What platform are you running it on?

Comment: It worked for me when I installed pydicom and sympy. I am using Windows 10 platform.